# Change thebackground color of the body on click with JS

Tags: javascript

I want to change the bg of the body when the user clicks on a button (Click here to change the color of the background of the body) on the top of the page;
here is the page:https://relaxed-ardinghelli-701d99.netlify.app/
I managed to do it only once; I used the for loop so the same code gets executed 10 or 20 times.. but it is not working:

```
for(let i=0; i<100; i++){
bg_button.addEventListener("click", funct2);
function funct2(e) {
body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey"
section_top.style.backgroundColor="white"
bg_button.addEventListener("click", funct3);

function funct3(e) {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    section_top.style.backgroundColor=""}}}
```

Comment: why need to execute 10 or 20 times ?

Comment: I am just learning the DOM ; it is just my imagination that told me this lol

Comment: Something you should know about JS in the browser is that when called, any regular event handler will execute completely before returning control to the browser to paint the updated content. A for-loop won't stop after one iteration to pick back up on the next button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the button to toggle the background color no matter how many times you click it, you can do it in a single event listener that updates a state variable:

```js
let toggleState = false

function toggleBackground() {
  toggleState = !toggleState
  if (toggleState) {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey"
    section_top.style.backgroundColor="white"
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    section_top.style.backgroundColor=""
  }
}

bg_button.addEventListener("click", toggleBackground);
```

Or you can **replace** the event listener instead of adding a new one on click:

```js
function setBg1() {
  body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey"
  section_top.style.backgroundColor="white"
  bg_button.onclick = setBg2
}

function setBg2() {
  body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
  section_top.style.backgroundColor=""
  bg_button.onclick = setBg1
}

bg_button.onclick = setBg1
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, it is working like a charm! can you explain the first snippet of code a little bit please?
JS is indeed an ocean ! can I master JS by practicing a lot and building projects?

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK You want your button to switch the background between two states. Rather than setting a new EventListener every time that state changes, this example defines a *single EventHandler* that gets attached to the button *once* and handles the click in either state. The event handler chooses its behaviour based on the variable that is kept and updated outside the function every time it is called.

If this solution worked for you, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Note that if you attach a second listener with `addEventListener` like you did originally, they will *both* be called unless you unregister the other one with `removeEventListener`. That's why my second example assigns a single listener to the `onclick` property instead.

Comment: can you help me , with something else ? : 
When you slick on the button "collapse all", I want the section 2 to be collapsed slowly and  smoothly (over the course of 4 or 5 seconds), how can I do this please ?
https://relaxed-ardinghelli-701d99.netlify.app/

Comment: I'd like to do something like that with pure CSS but I think animating an element to shrink from automatic size (calculated from content) to 0 is something CSS famously can't do cleanly. You can however use js to temporarily make the size absolute https://jsfiddle.net/2k371dcm/79/

Comment: Here's a version of that fiddle with a button instead of having the section be clickable: https://jsfiddle.net/zm59wuv1/

Comment: thanks a lot man , you are awesome ! I can apply this to any content inside the div, not only text , right ?

Comment: Should work with any content, as long as you keep it in a .collapsible div

Comment: best way? beats me. For the most part, I learned from documentation how the builtin functions and the various browser APIs work, MDN Web Docs has most of those covered p well. I also bought a Udemy course named JavaScript: Understanding The Weird Parts which covered a lot of topics like `this` binding and the event loop. You can find the first 3.5 hours on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change background color on button click, you should use JavaScript function and change a style in the HTML page.

```
function chBackcolor(color) {
   document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

It is a function in JavaScript for change color, and you will be call this function in your event, for example :

```
<input type="button" onclick="chBackcolor('red');">
```

If you want it only for some seconds, you can use setTimeout function:

```
window.setTimeout("chBackColor()",10000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you an use the following function:

```
function bgColorToggle () {
   const availableColors = ['blue','red'];
   for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
     let color = availableColors[i%2];
     setTimeout((document.body.style.color = color),2000);
   }
}
```

Comment: This won't toggle colors over multiple calls. You're not even passing a function to `setTimeout`. It'll just switch the color between blue and red a hundred times in the same frame and then throw a hundred errors two seconds later.

Comment: actually, it'll already throw a syntax error before that because of `int i`

Comment: It's good to test code before submitting it to catch basic syntax errors like this.

Comment: yep! you got it man